# Why are integers converted to octal numbers here?

Tags: c++, c

I am unable to understand output of below mentioned program-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i, a[8]={000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111};

for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
   printf("%d\t",a[i]);             
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

---

OUTPUT -

0    1    8    9    100    101    110    111

Why are the initial four values getting converted here???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any integer literal that starts with a `0` followed by other digits is octal, just like any integer literal starting with `0x` or `0X`, followed by digits, is hexadecimal. C++14 will add `0b` or `0B` as a prefix for binary integer literals.

See more on [integer literals in C++ here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Answer (score 2):

If you start a number with a `0` it gets converted to an octal number

0xNumber is hex

Comment: Please add that 0x will do hex.